# Joi validate Dates for range and exact date

Tags: date, joi

I am working on a date input for interfacing with stripe. When testing we need to allow the specific date of 01/01/1901 but for all other cases we need to ensure that the birthdate is 18 or more years ago but not more than 100 years ago. This last part I can easily do with the following joi command

```
Joi.date().format("MM/DD/YYYY").raw().required().max(<a specific date value>).min(<Another Date Value>).messages(errorMessages)
```

My question is, for the sake of testing we need to allow specific dates to pass validation and I'm wondering if there is a way to have joi validate dates between a range or dates that are exactly equal to

thanks for any advice and help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. This can be achieved using [`any.alternatives()`](https://joi.dev/api/?v=17.4.1#alternatives) and [`any.valid()`](https://joi.dev/api/?v=17.4.1#anyvalidvalues---aliases-equal).

The following will allow your range rule plus a list of arbitrary dates `['01/01/1901', '12/12/2020']`

```
Joi.object().keys({
    date: Joi.alternatives(
        Joi.date().format("MM/DD/YYYY").raw().required().max(<a specific date value>).min(<Another Date Value>).messages(errorMessages),
        Joi.any().valid('01/01/1901', '12/12/2020')
    )
})
```

Comment: Whaaat?? This is so crazy. I will try this Right away.